# What is the point of upvoted comments

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-voting

Is there any benefit of your comments being upvoted because I have a few and nothing is happening?

Comment: It just indicates that its useful and if anyones just scanning the comments they should read it, it has no other effect (apart from a badge)

Comment: @RichardTingle You only posted that as a comment so you could demonstrate the answer, didn't you? ;)

Comment: Comment upvotes all round

Comment: Lol everything here has upvotes ;)

Comment: I've now actually run out of my comment upvotes for the day, i'm blaming you @user2568107

Comment: Ha ha ha ha ha ha

Comment: Hey who downvoted my question???

Comment: @user2568107 +1, good question, I have actually wondered this myself.  Thank you for the answers all, explained nicely.

Comment: @user2568107 Not me, I was considering upvoting but guess what I've also run out of

Comment: Also, You can earn [a badge for upvoted comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/pundit)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It just indicates that the comment is useful and if anyone is just scanning the comments they should read it. These comments are also shown preferentially if only some of the comments are being shown.

It has no other effect (apart from a [badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/pundit))

Answer (score 11):

When a question has many comments only some are displayed, preferred visibility is given to the comments with the most upvotes.  This can be important to have a later comment be shown without expanding all comments.